# How to find Opecv function's original code

Tags: function, opencv3.0

Hi I would like to read the code of the function StereoSGBM,
how can i find it inside the opencv library?
There is a short command to find it from the python prompt?

Comment: look at `github` . It's c++ with intrinsics and others. So i doubt you'll be glad when see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the source code of the function "StereoSGBM" from [the link here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/stereosgbm.cpp)

You can also find the nice example of using this function in Python [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/stereo_match.py)

Addtionally, you can find the example of using this function in C++ [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stereo_match.cpp)